# Basic Web Development Questions (building a working test site)

Tags: sql, database, backend, web-development-server

I am new to this site and coding. I have self taught myself html and I understand css. I have been putting together a site of mine using my basic knowledge. I have no college experience but this is MY DREAM to put this site together so I have done a lot of research and read books to get started but I have hit a roadblock now. Here is what I have done:

-I have put together all of the front end pages and design using html/css. So, I have all of the pages that would be involved with the site, ready to go. All designed and have the layout how I wish it to be.

I guess I would call it the "skeleton" of the site. Any page that a user would be directed to, I have in a folder.

I have put together a little "demo" for myself to mimic a user experience. For example, I created a login page that "looks" how i want it to be but it doesnt actually store or save any logins.

This is my first question:

What is my next step? I admit it sounds stupd but I am self taught and I really have the ambition to acheive this I just can not figure out where to go from here in order to actually make a functioning site. All I have right now is my html "demo" where basically I have to follow a certain path down my site that mimics what a user would do on the site. I have it now where I click on the "sign up" button on my html form and it basically just redirects to my "new user" page. Then it is the same formula throughout the rest of my demo. I just put my other html pages I have designed into the html to sort of give a "user experience" to the demo. But I REALLY want to be able to have working accounts and saved data.

How do I create/save a user login to my site? DO i need to get a sql database? Is there a free one to use while i build the site? Honestly i really need  someone who is willing to help me out with the steps in this journey without me sharing my entire site (i wish to keep it to my self) but.. i understand this is basic web stuff i just am genuinely lost as how to take it to the next level. I have all of the html done and now i need a way to actually make it work. I wish to conversate with someone please about this kink in the chain i am seeming to find myself in please. Thank you so much and I would be grateful. :)

----basically what programming languages do i need to learn, or when looking for someone to hire, what should they be skilled in? any software or sites or databases that i need? please help!!!

Comment: You're looking for a PHP/MySQL tutorial.

Comment: Unfortunately this is just too broad a question, as most anything will "work". Since you're not a programmer yet, it's hard to suggest something more specific, there's honestly just too many paths, all good paths. Throw a dart and pick something, just find something that catches your eye and move forward. You can always change course later.

Comment: You will need something to do the dynamic part of your site.  And a database to store the data into.  It could be done in text files but that is not efficient nor recommended.  Look at PHP (server side language which integrates great with html), and MySQL or PostgreSQL for free databases.  It could be done in Java (is you already have some knowledge there), or Ruby, or.Net, ...  I suggest PHP because that is what I know.  Now as far as SO is concerned, this will be flaged as out of scope, since it is primarily opinion based...

Comment: Also, as someone else mentioned on another post -- drop in to chat. Folks will be more able to answer your question there and talk more about what's involved.

Comment: Find a database of some kind that will allow you to store data.

Comment: Thank you all! Even this basic info is helping me tbh. I am learning fast because I am really motivated to make this site, it's just a bunch of chaos right now but I am taking it in, So thanks. I am leaning towards learning all I can about php/mysql, do i need to have a domain registered to use the functions php or sql offer? I DO have a domain registered already but I faintly remember having a college room mate building and testing his site at home on his laptop. Doyou suggest just downloading php from their main site and finding a free database like microsoft sql express? and just diving in?

Comment: @hudoxai For local development, if you do go with PHP/MySQL, I'd suggest searching to 'install xampp' on your OS. This will give you a development stack with a web server, php, mysql (and perl, but don't worry too much about that).

Comment: Jeez thank you so much you all! I installed xammp as a starting point and am studying these new paths I need to learn now haha. (php, sql, etc) I was really lost, hopefully i can get it and provide more in depth questions next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML and CSS are the languages that make up the front end of a website, like you said. In order for your website to have dynamic content (content specific to a user) and the ability to actually process logins, etc., there needs to be a server involved. A webpage is a text document that is interpreted by a browser. HTML makes up the content and CSS tells the browser how you want it to look. What you are missing, primarily, is server scripts, most commonly, in my experience, PHP. You can also include JavaScript for client-side effects.

Specific to your question about a user login, yes, you will need a database. The process should look something like this.

1. User visits login page
2. User enters information into an HTML form
3. User clicks submit
4. Form is submitted to a server URL using the 'POST' method
5. Server validates the form content
6. Server checks database for username or email (whichever you are using)
7. If the username/email exists, it compares the passwords
8. Server sends a response back to the client, either good or bad

Once the user is validated, you can redirect the user to the dashboard or user section.

Please keep in mind this is a very simplistic version of events. There are more in depth steps that need to be taken, for example, your passwords should never be stored in a database as plain text, you should use a one-way encryption (hashing) algorithm to make them unreadable. Then when a password is given to the server it should be hashed and you should compare the hashes. You can also use salts when hashing for more security. The form should use SSL to prevent man in the middle attacks, etc.

Sounds like you are off to a good start, but in order to make it work you have to add the server logic. Self-teaching will get you as far as you are willing to let it. I taught myself how to do web programming, and now I do it as a business. The Internet is a great resource. There are a ton of great tutorials online that will show you how to do everything I just laid out.

Comment: It is all so much haha, but I am dedicated to this. It's fun and feels like it's what i have to do so I am willing to let it take me to the moon my friend! Thanks for the basic layout there. So first step is i need a web server? Where do i even start with that? lol. I already got like ten tabs open from all the suggestions here haha. But from what i am reading.. I need a web server..and a database..then using php code i can send the user data in my html form to send it to the database..on a webserver... correct?

Comment: Here is a basic tutorial on PHP and user logins. It uses PHP Data Object (PDO) for the database handling (one of many methods, just the one I've used in the past). As for the server, if you want it accessible online you will need to get a server from one of the many companies online. If you are just using the website for development and yourself, you can download something like XAMPP which is a local server that runs on your computer and should have database software.  Here is the link to the tutorial: [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/06/php-login-script-using-pdo-with-session.html)

Comment: Thank you @thomas I downloaded xampp and will start learning as much as i can!  it's starting to make more sense to me now, and yes i will be building the site locally for now until i am confident in the final product. :) Thank you for the link as well my friend!